# I changed Volumegroup name via Webmin, now I can't boot. Stuck on initramfs

Tags: boot, server, vmware, lvm, initramfs

I will summarise how I created this error.

I created a lvm, then changed the name of volumegroup. It was *ubuntuvm-vg* I renamed it *ubuntuvmvg*. I mounted lvm volume fine and to make sure it also auto mounts I rebooted my ubuntu server running on Vmware. Now I'm stuck on initramfs screen.
This is my test server, there's nothing important in it. But instead of reinstalling the server I'd rather know how to fix this issue.
Here's a screenshot if that helps
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZ7Ha.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update initramfs

First start from a live USB-Device or DVD.

You need to install lvm:

```
$ sudo apt-get install lvm
```

Now mount it:

```
$ sudo mount /dev/sdX /mnt
```

where X is your ubuntu partition.

Change into your ubuntu system:

```
sudo mount -o bind /dev /mnt/dev
sudo mount -o bind /sys /mnt/sys 
sudo mount -t proc /proc /mnt/proc
sudo cp /proc/mounts /mnt/etc/mtab 
sudo chroot /mnt /bin/bash 
sudo update-initramfs -k all -u
sudo reboot
```

Now it should work.

Comment: Not sure what you mean change into your ubuntu system.

Comment: with chroot you can change into your ubuntu system on your hdd.
See this for more informations: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCdRecovery